# Moving Transformation Anchor Point in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transform

I have a form layer containing two paths in PS CC, when I transform it (using `cmd+T`) I would like to move the central anchor point, unfortunately, when I click-drag on it, it moves all the layer, and not the only central anchor point.

Have I missed something somewhere? Is it locked for this type of layer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't missed anything. What you're doing is correct, but you may have to wait for a moment before you start to drag, depending on how much memory your machine has. (Photoshop swaps bits of itself in and out based on how much memory is available and how much it needs. This can occasionally cause some user interactions to fail briefly, then work thereafter.)

And you do have to click quite precisely on that center dot!

Other troubleshooting things I would do, if that's not working:

- Copy the layer and see if the copy has the same problem.
- Select and copy the shapes, then paste to a new layer.
- Select and copy the shapes to a new document. (Copy back to your original and delete the rogue layer if that clears it.)
- Delete Photoshop preferences and try again.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it is not working. My machine is a i7 QuadCore with 16Gb of RAM and a SSD. In fact I have noticed this happened on only one of my layers. Other form layers can have their anchor point moved. With the faulty layer, when I hover the central anchor point, the mouse cursor does not change, whereas it changes for the other layers (in which I can move the anchor point). So maybe I have locked something in this one... I'm lost.

Comment: You might want to carefully check all the lock icons in the Layers panel to make sure none are active, but I've added a few other tips to the answer -- things I would do in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you just have to hold down alt key wile you move it, anchor point will move but it will reset each time you select transform again.